# Delete the file without knowing its type

Tags: php, unlink

Can I delete the file without knowing its type in php?
I want to do something like this:

```
unlink('../gallery/images/pic23.?)
```

How can I perform this ?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all of the files with [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) and then delete them individually, like this:

```
foreach( glob( '../gallery/images/pic23.*') as $file) {
    unlink( $file);
}
```